# What processes contribute to non-relativistic proton-antiproton collsions (annihilation)

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I wonder what the dominant contributions of nuclear interaction to non-relativistic proton-antiproton annihilation are (I mean that the proton and antiproton are non-relativistic. The products might be.). Naively I would try to draw graphs with $\pi_0$ exchange. Would this yield a correct estimate? But I am not even sure whether $p\bar{p}\rightarrow\gamma\gamma$ is the most important process. At relativistic energies I suspect that quark-antiquark interactions etc. need to be taken into account. When exactly would this be the case?

Comment: The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation) cites http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0501020, which looks quite thorough.